# How to change a windows path to a linux path in all files under a directory using sed

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I copied a directory structure from a windows box to a Linux box and I would like to use sed to replace `c:\IBM\WebSphere` with `/opt/IBM/WebSphere` in all files under this directory.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "copied a directory structure"?  Are all the files from the Windows box now on the Linux box?  If so, haven't all the paths already been constructed in a Linux fashion?

Comment: The are all on the Linux box, but some of the files have paths hardcoded in them, so I need to access each file and change the path to the new Linux path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sed is a little inconvenient for that purpose, if you want to change the actual files you can use perl one-liner

```
perl -pi -e 's/c:\\IBM\\/\/opt\/IBM\//g' *
```

Add or adjust the paths according to what you need (add WebSphere if you want the replacement to change only these dirs)

Answer (score 0):

Since `sed` can take any character as a delimiter, use

```
sed -e 's_\\_/_g'
```

to replace the `\` to `/`.

```
sed -e 's_[Cc]:_/opt_g'
```

to replace the `c:` with `/opt`

You can string those together:

```
echo "C:\\IBM\\WebSphere" | sed -e 's_\\_/_g' -e 's_[Cc]:_/opt_g'
```

Output:

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere
```

Comment: The only problem I see with that is that there are some "\" that need to stay as they are, so I couldn't run the sed to replace all "\" with "/".  It has to be the complete "C:\IBM\WebSphere"

Comment: @user2292500: in that case you need to update your question explaining a) the fact that some need to stay unchanged and b) give people criteria to tell the difference between a \ that needs to stay and one that needs to go.

Comment: Will it ever NOT be `C:\IBM\WebSphere`? If not, `sed -e 's_[Cc]:\\IBM\\WebSphere_/opt/IBM/WebSphere_'` will do it. If it's `C:\[path1]\[path2]` and you need to replace whatever is in `path1` and `path2` in the output, then you'll need to specify as such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an awk solution, just add one:

```
awk -F'\' -v OFS='/' '$1=/^c:/?"/opt":$1'
```

test:

```
kent$  awk -F'\' -v OFS='/' '$1=/^c:/?"/opt":$1' <<<'c:\IBM\WebSphere'  
/opt/IBM/WebSphere
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo  "C:\Users\San.Tan\My Folder\project1" | sed -e 's/C:\\/mnt\/c\//;s/\\/\//g'`

replaces

`C:\Users\San.Tan\My Folder\project1`

to

`mnt/c/Users/San.Tan/My Folder/project1`

in case someone needs to replace windows paths to Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL) paths