# Using sed command how can I replace Linux path to Windows path

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to change the Linux path to a Windows Path, using "sed" command, for example:

> Linux path: **/opt/test/dash/apps/tomcat** to Windows Path:
>   **c:\\test\\dash\\apps\\tomcat**

I tried with:

```
sed -i 's|'/opt/test/dash/apps/tomcat'|'c:\\\\\\\test\\\\\\\dash\\\\\\\apps\\\\\\\tomcat'|g' /filename - But no luck!!
```

What I exactly want all /opt/ should replace by c:\\ and rest of the "/" should be replace by "\\".

NOTE: I am executing this command remotely using ssh2_exec, All "sed" commands are working except the above.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `sed` will butcher end-of-line. It converts them to Linux `LF` even on Windows where `CR-LF` is used. You should run `unix2dos.exe` to repair them after running `sed` on your source file.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to change a windows path to a linux path in all files under a directory using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23529669/608639), [Bash script to convert windows path to linux path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19999562/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two steps:

```
$>echo '/opt/test/dash/apps/tomcat' | sed 's#/opt#c:#g'|sed 's#/#\\\\#g'
c:\\test\\dash\\apps\\tomcat
```

First changing the `/opt` with `c:`, then change the `/` with `\` that you have to escape

Comment: Hi Thanks, but how can I apply the same command to a group of files?
Like: sed 's#/opt#c:#g'|sed 's#/#\\\\#g' *.properties

Comment: I would use a for loop: `for i in *properties; do sed -i 's#/opt#c:#g'|sed 's#/#\\\\#g' $i;done`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regular expressions and so:

```
sed -r 's@/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)@C:\\\\\2\\\\\3\\\\\4\\\\\5@'
```

Using -r to enable interpretation of regular expressions and @ as the sed separator, split the path in 5 parts and then refer to them in the translated section with \1 \2 etc.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I execute the same command to change the contents inside the file, Like : sed -r 's@/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)@C:\\\\\2\\\\\3\\\\\4\\\\\5@'  <file-Name>

Comment: Working with the following command sed -i -r 's@/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)@C:\\\\\2\\\\\3\\\\\4\\\\\5@' *.properties